# Can I use str.append to create a new string with no vowels?

Tags: c++, string, iterator, append

I'm doing a practice assignment from codewars.com to create a program that will take a troll's comments and transform it into a statement with no vowels.

My idea is to get the comment, return all the characters that are not vowels and put it in a new string array using an iterator.

```
int main()
{
    string troll;
    string disemvoweled;
    
    getline(cin,troll);
    int length= (int) troll.length();
    
    string::iterator it;
    
    for (it = troll.begin();it!=troll.end();it++) {
        if (*it!='a' || *it!='e' || *it!='i' || *it!='o' || *it!='u' || *it!='A' || *it!='E' ||*it!='I' || *it!='O' || *it!='U'){
            disemvoweled.append(*it);
        }
    }
    cout << disemvoweled;

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error:

```
no matching function for call to std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::append(char&)'
```

My first question is why is the append() not working?

My second question is, without providing any solution, which concept of C++ can help me improve this code? I was thinking perhaps using a container of some sort and popping out a vowel?

Comment: You can't append char's to strings directly. For your final solution have a look at the following building blocks : std::set (vowels), std::ostringstream (string building) and range based for loops (more readable then iterator loops).

Comment: There's also a logic error - You only want to append if all of the != eval to true, so all the ors (||) should be ands (&&)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append a char to a std::string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1472048/90527)

Answer (score 0):

> why is the append() not working?

The overloads for `append` can be found [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) and as you can see they expect argument of different types(like `const std::string&` and `const char*)` while you're providing the `char` type argument.

You can **solve** this by using `+=` as follows:

```
disemvoweled+= (*it);
```

> which concept of C++ can help me improve this code?

You can **improve** the code by using `std::set` as follows:

```
getline(cin,troll);
std::set<char> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E','I','O','U'};

for (auto it = troll.begin();it!=troll.end();it++) {
    if (vowels.find(*it) == vowels.end())
    {
        disemvoweled+= (*it); //can also use disemvoweled.append(1, *it);
    }
}
cout << disemvoweled;
```

Comment: Could also use `push_back`.

Comment: @Yes but IMO `+=` is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

constexpr bool is_not_vowel(char const ch) noexcept {
    switch (ch) {
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': 
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "hello world";
    std::string no_vowels;
    ranges::copy(
        str | ranges::views::filter(is_not_vowel),
        std::back_inserter(no_vowels)
    );

    std::cout << no_vowels << '\n';
}
```

[See online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jxhao6czn)